Duplicate Kdenlive applications on Ubuntu Gnome snap software store
I was recently looking to install Kdenlive on Gnome Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using the snap software store. However, I noticed that the search feature returned 2 applications both labeled Kdenlive with the same thumbnail. Visiting both, they had the same reviews, but different descriptions, versions, and verification status. One was version 23.08.4 and considered Safe, and the other was version 21.12.3 and Potentially Unsafe. Is this a bug or is something malicious going on?

Does this answer your question? Why are the two versions of Chromium and VLC available in Ubuntu software of different sizes?

This question is not a duplicate of the Why do two separate packaging formats exist in the Software app? question as it is a question about Why is one of two Kdenlive packages in the Software app referred to as Potentially Unsafe?.

Kdenlive version 23.08.4 is packaged as a snap package. Snap access to the rest of the system is defined by a set of interfaces, and the user can turn any of these interfaces off or on after the snap package is installed. This feature provides some additional security. Also snap packages are usually updated more frequently than .deb packages which means they receive security updates more frequently than .deb packages do.
In Ubuntu snap packages are self-contained applications bundled with their dependencies and configured to run in a sandboxed environment. Snap package "sandboxing" refers to the security feature that isolates these packages from the rest of the operating system.
Kdenlive version 21.12.3 is packaged as a .deb package in Ubuntu 22.04. The Kdenlive .deb package is maintained by Kubuntu Developers. The Software app might still flag it as third party because, even though Kubuntu is Ubuntu-based and associated with Canonical, it's a separate project with its own focus on the KDE desktop environment. Snap packages are packaged differently than .deb packages in a way that makes them compatible with all of the desktop environments that are available in the default Ubuntu repositories.

So there are apt-based packages on the Ubuntu Software Store?

In the regular Ubuntu Software app that has an orange basket icon there are both apt and snap packages. There is also another software app called the Snap Store that has only snap packages. The Snap Store has blue basket icon.

I see. I recently had problems with my store and uninstalled and reinstalled. I ran sudo snap install snap-store, but it gave me the orange basket one. This is actually what I wanted, because I wanted to reinstall the default, but I thought I had installed the snap one based on the command I used.

If I run the snap-store command in my Ubuntu 22.04 it launches the blue basket one.

Interesting. If I run the same command, I get the orange basket one.

Also, just wanted to add for those who care to distinguish the snap and apt versions, you can identify the package manager associated with an app on the Ubuntu Software Store in the Source dropdown in the top right of the window in the title bar by the minimize, fullscreen, and close buttons.

Maybe the information in the comments here can provide some insight into the Ubuntu's store naming conventions and how each is installed and referenced, although it seems to contradict the behavior I have experienced.
